# Disable keyboard search in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I am using a `QTableWidget` that I fill it with text only items. If I select a cell and press a key, the selection changes to a cell that has the pressed key as its starting letter. How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your own TableWidget class inheriting the QTableWidget class and override the virtual keyboardSearch() function with an empty implementation. This will disable the keyboard search functionality.

```
class MyTableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
...
public:
  virtual void keyboardSearch(const QString& search) {};
...
};
```

Comment: yes, this is the function i needed. But i tryed to avoid inheriting from QTableWidget. At the moment i created the table with the Qt designer and install an eventFilter. Is there a possible way for catching the "keyboardSearch" by event?

Comment: That works too, but by filtering keyboard events you may interfere with other states (such as editing state) of the QTableWidget where you don't want to filter keyboard events. You may eventually end up with quite complicated code to do the right thing. The clean and safest way of doing it is overriding keyboardSearch(). It's easy, you don't need to do much more than what I did in the code example, and once done you can use your class in Qt Designer. This is most easily done by right-clicking on the QTableWidget in your widget in Qt Designer and choosing "Promote to...".

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution has the problem that the QAbstractItemView derived type (QTableWidget) still will accept and thereby steal all kinds of key events. For example if you'd want to close a parent widget when the `q` key is pressed, you wouldn't get the `q` key press event.

Looking at the source code for `QAbstractItemView::keyPressEvent`, the keyboard search is only triggered when the event text is non-empty. So, I found it a better solution to overwrite `keyPressEvent`, clear this text in the event, and then call the base class implementation:

```cpp
class MyTable :
    public QTableView
{
public:
    void
    keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* event ) override
    {
        /* Clear text in order to avoid keyboardSearch being triggered */
        QKeyEvent textClearedEvent( event->type(),
                                    event->key(),
                                    event->modifiers(),
                                    event->nativeScanCode(),
                                    event->nativeVirtualKey(),
                                    event->nativeModifiers(),
                                    QString(),
                                    event->isAutoRepeat(),
                                    event->count() );

        QTableView::keyPressEvent( &textClearedEvent );

        event->setAccepted( textClearedEvent.isAccepted() );
    }
```

This would even work without inheriting by installing a similar event filter.